# kebab-case to camelCase via localsConvention in css-loader 3.4.2 not working

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, create-react-app, css-loader

For testing/learning purposes I am using an ejected version of `create-react-app 3.4.1` which comes with `css-loader 3.4.2`, and I am trying to reproduce [these results](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#namedexport) where the css selectors are written in kebab-case, but the js styles object converts them to camelCase:

**styles.css**

```
.foo-baz {
  color: red;
}
.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import styles from './styles.css';

console.log(styles);
// expected result: { fooBaz, bar }
// actual, default results: { foo-baz, bar }
```

According to the css-loader [changelog](https://openbase.io/js/css-loader/versions#3.0.0) in version 3.0.0:

> `exportLocalsStyle` option was remove in favor `localsConvention` option, also it is accept only `{String}` value (use `'camelCase'` value if you previously value was `true` and `'asIs'` if you previously value was `false`)

So I tried to do that:

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
{
  test: cssRegex,
  exclude: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
    localsConvention: "camelCase", // my only addition is this line
  }),
  sideEffects: true,
},
...
```

Running `npm start` and `npm run build` both work successfully, however the conversion does not happen and I am still stuck with kebab-case in my js files, even when adding a `console.log(styles)` on my App.js file, the output object printed to the console is still kebab-case keys and subsequent kebab-case values.

Am I missing something here? Perhaps It's very possible I don't have a clear understanding on the pre/post css compiling process and I am attempting to inject this logic in the wrong place? Does anyone have a working example of utilizing this kebab to camelCase capabilities in `css-loader 3.*`?

Sidenote: I do not want to update the `css-loader` package to it's latest version, I am intending on bringing this information back into a non-ejected `create-react-app` and then update the config with `craco` - the less I have to change the better.

Comment: did you get this resolved ?

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed by exportLocalsConvention in modules section:

```
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: {
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:6]',
            exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you definitely using css-loader 3.4.2 ?

Comment: Not sure what version I was using at the time of writing, atm on 5.2.4 and it's working. I'm trying to always be on the latest.

Comment: This is the correct answer as of writing, based on the documentation. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by specifying `localsConvention` option as,

```js
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
     options: { 
        modules: {
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
        },
        localsConvention: 'camelCase'
     }
},
```

Hope this helps someone, as I had to spend few hours to find the correct fix.

Comment: This is only for old versions of css-loader. As of writing, the updated config is the above answer. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: Yes, this question is about `css-loader 3.4.2`. So, if you are using an old version you will have to specify the options this way.