# Convert CSS module kebab-case class names to camelCase in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules

I'm using CSS modules (`.scss`) with Next.js and have a kebab naming-convention. In other words, something like this:

```
.member-btn {
    background: #fff;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that in order to use this with `className` I have to do it like `styles["member-btn"]`. E.g.

```scss
<Button className={styles["member-btn"]}>
    Hello world
</Button>
```

However, I would like to use it with `styles.memberBtn` and use it like an object (IDE also provides built-in support for this). E.g.

```scss
<Button className={styles.memberBtn}>Hello world</Button>
```

Is this possible in Next.js?

Comment: Why not to use camel case directly? maybe you can find something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693309/kebab-case-to-camelcase-via-localsconvention-in-css-loader-3-4-2-not-working or similar questions

Comment: @lissettdm I think `kebab-case` is more standard when you write css codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next.js doesn't provide an easy, built-in way to customise CSS Modules options yet (see related RFC [vercel/next.js#15818](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15818)). This means you have to dig into webpack and customise the `css-loader` used by Next.js directly in your `next.config.js`.

Here's a potential solution that works for the latest Next.js versions, based off the answers in [vercel/next.js#11267](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11267).

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    // other existing configurations here...
    webpack: (config) => {
        const rules = config.module.rules
            .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === 'object').oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));
        rules.forEach((rule) => {
            rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
                if (
                    moduleLoader.loader !== undefined 
                    && moduleLoader.loader.includes('css-loader') 
                    && typeof moduleLoader.options.modules === 'object'
                ) {
                    moduleLoader.options = {
                        ...moduleLoader.options,
                        modules: {
                            ...moduleLoader.options.modules,
                            // This is where we allow camelCase class names
                            exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase'
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

The idea is to target the `css-loader` used internally by Next.js and overwrite the `exportLocalsConvention` option to `'camelCase'`. This enables the usage of camelCased class names, e.g. `styles.memberBtn`.

Answer (score 5):

This is what solved my issue, it converts all css module classnames to camelCase

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        // camelCase style names from css modules
        config.module.rules
            .find(({oneOf}) => !!oneOf).oneOf
            .filter(({use}) => JSON.stringify(use)?.includes('css-loader'))
            .reduce((acc, {use}) => acc.concat(use), [])
            .forEach(({options}) => {
                if (options.modules) {
                    options.modules.exportLocalsConvention = 'camelCase';
                }
            });

        return config;
    },
};
```